# Redeclare variables defined in global scope with a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, loops, declare

I am trying to redeclare variables defined in global scope. I'd like to wrap each function

```
const {values, map, each} = require('lodash')

const wrapFnInLog = (fn) => (...input) => {
  console.log({name: fn.name, input})
  const possiblePromise = fn.apply(null, input)
  if (get(possiblePromise, 'then')) {
    return possiblePromise.then(output => {
      console.log({name: fn.name, output})
      return output
    })
  } else {
    console.log({name: fn.name, output: possiblePromise})
    return possiblePromise
  }
}

let a = (arr) => map(arr, i => i.name)
let b = (obj) => a(values(obj))

const provide = [a, b]

provide.forEach(fn => wrapFnInLog(fn))

const example = {
  personTom: {
    name: 'Tom'
  },
  personJerry: {
    name: 'Jerry'
  }
}

b(example)
```

I'd like the output to look like this:

```
{ name: 'b', input: [ { personTom: [Object], personJerry: [Object] } ] }
{ name: 'a', input: [ [ [Object], [Object] ] ] }
{ name: 'a', output: [ 'Tom', 'Jerry' ] }
{ name: 'b', output: [ 'Tom', 'Jerry' ] }
```

The only way I've been able to achieve this is without a loop and it's via deliberately overwriting each variable one by one.

```
a = wrapFnInLog(a)
b = wrapFnInLog(b)
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to loop over `[a, b]` and overwrite the function definition, while keeping them in global module scope.

Comment: There is no way to iterate over scoped variables (local or module level variables) like `a` and `b` in your example.  That's a Javascript limitation.  You have to put them in an object or an array in order to be able to iterate over them so they have an explicit container which you can iterate.

Comment: destructuring assignment `[a,b] = [a,b].map(wrapFnInLog);`

Comment: `if (possiblePromise.then) {` don't forget to check that `possiblePromise` ain't `null` or `undefined`

Comment: @Thomas your solution works, please post answer, just also emphasize comma is needed before it ;(

Comment: @ThomasReggi, alternatively you could start using semicoli, and not rely on JS getting your *intentions* right when it's inserting them.

Comment: Nit: `a` and `b` are module scope, not global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as already commented, you can use a destructuring assignment to assign multiple variables at once

```
let a = (arr) => map(arr, i => i.name);
let b = (obj) => a(values(obj));

[a,b] = [a,b].map(wrapFnInLog);
```

but unlike a destructuring assignment in combination with a variable declaration (`let [a,b] = ...`) you have to be careful what you write before this assignment and that you properly seperate commands.

Because with automatic semicolon insertation or, JS **not** inserting a semicolon where one should be,

```
let a = (arr) => map(arr, i => i.name)
let b = (obj) => a(values(obj))

[a,b] = [a,b].map(wrapFnInLog)
```

will be interpreted as

```
let a = (arr) => map(arr, i => i.name);
let b = (obj) => {
  return a(values(obj))[a,b] = [a,b].map(wrapFnInLog);
}
//or in other words
let b = (obj) => {
  let tmp1 = a(values(obj));
  a; //the `a,` in something[a,b];
  let tmp2 = [a,b].map(wrapFnInLog);
  tmp1[b] = tmp2;
  return tmp2;
}
```